# Python SQL query and store all matches to resizing list

Tags: python, sql, list, dynamic, mysql-python

I'd like to use Python to query a database and store all the matching records in a list.

What I am specifically stuck on is how to get each individual matching record into its own index in my list.

Is this redundant? Will the DB API do this for me already? Whatever the case, what is the best way to do this?

```
import argparse
import smtplib
import time
import sys
import multiprocessing
import MySQLdb
from datetime import datetime

""" Open database connection, make query and store all 
query matches into list """

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","DB")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE lastDate LIKE somedate")
rows = cursor.fetchall() #this is obviously wrong
print rows
db.close()
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: @DanielRoseman How to get each individual record that results after my query into a list.  For example, when sql returns my query, I need to get each record into its own index in my list.  I'm a bit unsure how to do this.

Comment: That is what the db api does for you already. Please show your code so far and explain where you are having difficulty.

Comment: @DanielRoseman See my edit above.  The code is storing all rows in a variable called rows but this isn't what I need.  I need to essentially store all matching individual records that are returned by my query into their own index in a list.

Comment: actually the list 'rows' is a list with each row in its own 'index' - try for row in rows: print row - and you will see they are seperate

Comment: I still don't understand what is "obviously wrong" about that code, or what you mean by "their own index". `rows` is a list of tuples, each tuple containing the fields from a single row. If that's not what you want, please can you show the data structure you need?

Comment: @gkusner I have now come to understand this.  So storing a fetchall() to a list and then iterating through that list using for lst in list worked great.  Thanks!